# React-navigation tutorial missing back button

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react native and I am following this tutorial from the official react-navigation docs on auth flow. 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

They have a really nice live example: https://snack.expo.io/@react-navigation/auth-flow-v3

After sign in, when you click on `Show me more of the app from the home screen`, it takes you to a page with a back button. Just from looking at the code, I can't figure out how they are able to produce this back button.

Maybe the code is not complete?

I understand that one way to a back button on the nav bar is to do something like:

```
headerLeft: (
  <Button
    onPress={() => alert('This is a button!')}
    title="Info"
    color="#fff"
  />
),
```

but this is missing from the code displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Navigation has by default provided Back button to navigate to the previous screen.

Because ios do not have a hardware back button all they have is a gesture with which they can go back. and if it is disabled then there is no way to go to the previous screen.

So default back button for stack navigator must be there and we have it.

So when there is a previous screen available back button will be there and if screen if first of its stack there will be no back button.

Let say we have one switch navigator for authentication screens like signIn, signUp etc. and one stack navigator for all other screens.

So here switch navigator by default has only one screen in its stack so none of these screens will have back button because you can't go back from here there is a dead end.

and for stack navigator, your first screen in the stack that renders before all other screens will not have a back button but all screens after that will be having back button because from there you can go back right.

Comment: Ok to summarize: stack navigator has back button by default and switch navigator does not?

Answer (score 1):

React Navigation already have default Header with back button when you create switch or stack navigator. the headerLeft property is only used if you want to override the default back button. :D

Edit:

to clear things out.

The purpose of SwitchNavigator is to only ever show one screen at a time. By default, it does not handle back actions and it resets routes to their default state when you switch away. -[switch navigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html#docsNav)

where stack navigator purposely create screen on top of a stack (if you have initial screen). initial screen wont have header with back button because it doesn't know where return to. thats why when you navigate to "OtherStack" it creates new screen named "OtherStack" place on the top of "HomeScreen". newly created screens have default header with back button so you can go back to initial stack.

```
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen });
```

Comment: Then how come `HomeScreen` and `SigninScreen` don't have it